# Can't serialize :last form that dynamically added

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to use scroll-pagination to make endless scroll page.
When scroll to the bottom of page,It will add new data and form at the bottom
but when i scroll to the bottom again , it doesn't serialize form that just dynamically add but it serialize first form.  ,Sorry for my english!
This is part my Jquery

```
$(function(){
var datastring=$(".passform:last").serialize();
$('#update').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': 'post_update.php',
    'contentData': {
        data : datastring
        }, 
    'scrollTarget': $(window), 
    'heightOffset': 10, 
    }
});});
```

This is my first form in my HTML

```
<form id="passform" class="passform" name="passform">
        <input name="totalpage" type="hidden" value="<? echo($totalpage);?>" />
        <input name="nowpage" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input name="u_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo($u_id);?>" />
        </form>
```

This is form that dynamically add later

```
 <form class="passform" id="passform2" name="passform2">
        <input name="totalpage" type="hidden" value="<? echo($totalpage);?>" />
        <input name="nowpage" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input name="u_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo($u_id);?>" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you executing `var datastring=$(".passform:last").serialize();` only on start-up? You might need to look into running it again after the new form  was added as it otherwise still is pointing to the previous form element.

Comment: try other ways of getting the last one. $(".passform").last() and $(".passform").eq(-1);

Comment: Francois is right actually...that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**plug-in site**](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/) there is a `afterLoad` option you can use similar to this:

```
var datastring;

$('#update').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': 'post_update.php',
    'contentData': {
        data: datastring
    },
    'scrollTarget': $(window),
    'heightOffset': 10,
    'afterLoad': function (elementsLoaded) {
        datastring=$(".passform:last").serialize();

        // or use elementsLoaded I suppose which should be the elements just loaded.
        //datastring=$(".passform", elementsLoaded).serialize();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 - Have no idea if it works, but great effort finding that Francois!

Comment: @adeneo: Thank you. Not sure myself though as I don't know the plug-in but according to the sample code on the site it seems to be usable for something like that. Sample code uses fade-in feature for new elements instead but it should be adoptable.

Comment: I'm still trying, but i think this must be the right way.Thank you!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Don't kmow why,But code still kept serialize the first form. I don't know how to but do you think live will help?

Comment: @Expl0de: Have also you tried the commented out line `datastring=$(".passform", elementsLoaded).serialize();`? That should try and look to find a form with the class of `.passform` within the context of the loaded elements.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I tried it already but still didn't work. I think its time to find another way :(

Comment: @Expl0de: Sorry to hear that. If you can somehow create a fiddle or maybe a public site to access for testing this, it would propably make it much easier for myself and others to try out some solutions and mess around with the code. I know this might not be possible, I'm just trying to think of other possible ways to be able to give you a hand.